Woocommerce custom states not showing in emails and orders
I needed to customize states and add different states for my country so i can divide shipping by regions and there is documentation on wc website but it's fairly simple and short. https://woocommerce.com/document/addmodify-states/
So I have the new list on here:
function custom_woocommerce_states( $states ) {
    $states['RS'] = array(
        'RS00' => 'Dorćol',
        'RS01' => 'Vračar',
        'RS02' => 'Palilula',
        'RS03' => 'Senjak',
        'RS04' => 'Dedinje',
    );
    return $states;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'custom_woocommerce_states' );


However even if this works in checkout page, when i receive an email and on order page, the name of the state is not there, but rather it's the key such as RS01
I can't find any other info on this on search, and the only link i found to wc support on this is closed without resolving the issue.
Am I missing something?

Here are some great examples on how you can do it with WP_User or WC_Order object.
